# joinChannel method : uid assignment

Tags: agora.io

The Agora.io doc is specifing for the joinChannel method :

> The user ID. A 32-bit unsigned integer with a value ranging from 1 to
>   (2^32 -1). This parameter must be unique. If uid is not assigned (or set
>   as 0), the SDK assigns a uid and reports it in the joinChannelSuccess
>   callback. The app must maintain this user ID.

I have 2 use cases :

1. For the users registered to my app : i want the app to assign an uid
2. For the users not registered to my app : I want to let agora.io decide of the uid

The issue is that doing so, I may get into collisions between userIds assigned by the app and usersIds assigned by agora lib.

But if you are assigning uids within a range of values (other than 1 -> 2^32) then i could rely on that.

Is it the case ?

thx.

Answer (score 2):

in this case, i think you can use the string user name to join the channel. You can take a look at this doc: https://docs.agora.io/en/faq/string